# Vue.js bulma modal not displayed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bulma

I'd like to open a modal when a link is clicked:

```
 <a @click="showEditModalFunc()" href="#">Edit Post</a>
```

The method:

```
  showEditModalFunc() {
    console.log('showEditModal value is' , this.showEditModal);
     this.showEditModal=!this.showEditModal;
  },
```

The modal itself:

```
<div v-if="showEditModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-background"></div>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <!-- Any other Bulma elements you want -->
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet  
  </div>
  <button class="modal-close is-large" aria-label="close"></button>
</div>
```

This should be straightforward, but the modal does not show up!

I don't get any error either. And I can see in the console `showEditModal value is true`.

The modal is using `bulma.css`. 
Strangely, I have another modal on the same component which I wrote when the component was using `bootstrap.css`. That modal  works just fine.

I'm wondering what could be wrong here? And how to fix it?

Comment: did you try `@click.prevent="showEditModalFunc()"`? by adding `.prevent` modifier

Comment: Well, I just tried `@click.prevent`, but to the same effect: No modal show up.

Answer (score 2):

According to the bulma.css documentation:

> To activate the modal, just add the is-active modifier on the .modal container

So you could use a class binding like so:

```
<div v-bind:class="{ 'is-active': showEditModal }" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-background"></div>
  <div class="modal-content">
    <!-- Any other Bulma elements you want -->
    Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet  
  </div>
  <button class="modal-close is-large" aria-label="close"></button>
</div>
```

Comment: Good point! But now the modal is always there even when `showEditModal` is false.

Comment: @qliq With Laurens' approach, you will also need to have this CSS class `is-active` altering the `display` style. You do have it, right?

Comment: @jom, not sure what you mean. I tried a terinary conditional like this,  `:class="{ showEditModal? "is-active": 'bla' }"`. but still does not work as it should. Besides that,  eslint complains that `'v-bind' directives require an attribute value`

Comment: @qliq I noticed `bulma.css` does seem to [have this `is-active` CSS class](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/css/bulma.css), but you might want to check if it applies for `div` elements as well. **Edit**: Nevermind, I think [it does](https://github.com/jgthms/bulma/blob/master/css/bulma.css#L5980).

Comment: @Laurens The correct syntax is: `<div :class="showEditModal ==true ? 'is-active' : 'bla'" class="modal">` Please modify and I'll accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: @qliq Laurens' solution should work too, I just tested it.

Comment: @qliq, why would you want to add 'bla' as a class when showEditModal is not true? My solution only adds is-active class when showEditModal == true (no need to include the == true part) and removes that class when showEditModal is false. bulma.css should take care of the rest..

Comment: @Laurens eslint on vscode complains that 'v-bind' directives require an attribute value

Comment: @qliq Are you using my exact code? I don't get that warning.. Vue.JS documentation also states the exact same syntax that I am using